# Change plotly scatterpolar labels manually

Tags: python, plotly

I have a scatterpolar plot, but the labels on the outside show the direction in terms of degrees rather than directions (N, NE, E, etc.). My data is in terms of degrees, so I will need to manually replace the labels shown on the plot. My current code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Get data
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpudil/projects/master/slc.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

fig = go.Figure(data=
    go.Scatterpolar(
        r = list(df['distance']),
        theta = list(df['bearing']),
        mode = 'markers',   
        name = 'log'
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    polar = dict(
      radialaxis = dict(type = "log", tickangle = 45),
      angularaxis = dict(
            thetaunit = "degrees",
            dtick = 45,
            rotation=90,
            direction = "clockwise" 
            )
    ))
```

Which produces the plot below. Any suggestions to make the plot show the direction instead of degree? Thanks.

[image]

Note: The data can be found at https://github.com/mpudil/projects/blob/master/slc.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way but the following should work

```py
fig.update_layout(
    polar = dict(
      radialaxis = dict(type = "log", tickangle = 45),
      angularaxis = dict(
            thetaunit = "degrees",
            dtick = 45,
            rotation=90,
            direction = "clockwise",
            tickmode="array",
            tickvals=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
            ticktext=["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"]
            )
    ))
```