# Change direction and rotation of a scatterpolar plot in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data set showing differences of two measurements of the same structure with two different methods as distance in meters and direction in degree. I found the scatterpolar plot of the function `plot_ly` of the package plotly in R, which produced almost what I wanted, but with some problems with the layout. Here is the code I used:

```
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(measurements_compare); data

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  r = c(data$distance),
  theta = c(data$rotation),
  text = c(data$id),
  mode = 'markers',
)

fig
```

What I got from that was this plot, which is already quite close to what I want:

[image]

Now I would like to rotate the plot so that 0° is at the top instead of 90°, also I would like the degrees to be plotted ascending clockwise instead of counterclockwise. I found code examples for that [in the archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184046/change-plotly-scatterpolar-labels-manually) where the function `update_layout`was used, but this example uses Python instead of R. I could not find something similar for R, but I am pretty sure there must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inn `plotly` you can oftten use the same arguments in R and Python. For your code Rs `layout` function is needed instead of Pythons `update_layout`.

**Example Data**

```
data <- data.frame(distance = sample(seq(.1, .5, by = .01),  15, T),
                   rotation  = sample(0:360, 15, T),
                   id = paste0(1:15))
```

**Code**

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  r = c(data$distance),
  theta = c(data$rotation),
  text = c(data$id),
  mode = 'markers',
) %>%
  layout(polar = list(
    angularaxis  = list(
      rotation = 90,
      direction = "clockwise"
    )
           ))

fig
```

**Plot**
[image]